# Linux Essentials Performance Based Lab - should I get it?

Tags: linux

I am doing Linux Essential course next month and want to know if I should get [this](http://www.lpimarketplace.com/Linux_Essentials_Performance_Based_Lab_p/llabslxess_p.htm) product to start learning now?  What is the benefit of this 'lab' as opposed to having a laptop set-up with a distribution?  I am actually confused, I initially thought it was a book.  Can someone advise if I should purchase it specifically for my LPI entry exam.  Thanks.

Comment: I honestly cannot tell what on Earth that product is supposed to be. Is it simulator software that runs on another computer?

Comment: No idea.  Do you know why there is no explanation on Linux Professional Institute website?  Seriously.  We must be missing something.  Unless you have a wealth of experience and the LPI people have done a bad job helping with the training material.  I really need guidance here.  Thanks :  )

Comment: Well, as a general rule of thumb, I would say that you shouldn't buy something if you can't even tell what category of thing it is.

Comment: Looking more closely at their description, it seems you'd be buying access to an online simulator in a Web app. I'd say it's not worth it; just use an old machine or install a VM, then download any Linux distro and mess around. All of this will be free.

Comment: Hi Tom, could you point me to a good instruction on installing a VM and then Linux - I'd love to know how to get started.  I am a complete beginner but love to get to the bottom of stuff.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30608/discussion-between-tom-hunt-and-user137810).

Answer (score 1):

I never used this product and really can't tell if it's worth or not buying it. But I studied by myself for this exam and got the LPIC-1 certification (in 2007).

Basically if you have no experience with Linux, I strongly recommend that you install it on an old computer/laptop or just buy a Raspbian. The distribution does not matter at first.

Install packages, change things/files/configs, recompile the kernel, play with the shell. "Break" the system and install it again. That's the only way to really learn and at the end it is going to make things so much easier for you.

After you get a little bit more experienced, just look on the LPI site what are the Exam topics - they are very clearly defined:

https://www.lpi.org/study-resources/lpic-1-101-exam-objectives/

So, just go one for one, read the man page of the command and try it out.

That's what I have done and after all it wasn't that difficult to pass the exam. And more important, I learnt A LOT of commands and tricks that I still use on my day-to-day at work.

Good luck!!

Comment: Sounds great.  I tried to see how to install on my OS X but did not find a structural supportive blog/help anywhere.  Is it possible to get Linux on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and how?  Apparently not easy.  I am concerned for what happens when the course starts!  Am doing it abroad so not easy to get in touch with training provider.  Thanks for help!

Comment: @user137810 Install VirtualBox or something, then install some Linux virts to experiment with.

Comment: Great.  Will try.

Comment: I have an MacBook Pro myself and installed Linux Mint (a friendly distribution similar to Ubuntu) on it, together with the OS X. You can either install it on a virtual machine, like thrig suggested VirtualBox - which I guess is safer for you or partition your HarDisk following this great instructions:

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1643

Comment: Hi.  Thanks loads, I'll keep in mind that for future.  I found a great VM instruction for now: [How to set up Ubuntu Linux on a Mac -- it's easy and free](http://www.engadget.com/2009/09/07/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-linux-on-a-mac-its-easy-and-free/).